# Nginx - Redirect www.example.com/test to www.example.com:3000/

Tags: nginx, routes

If I have a domain, for example, `http://www.example.com`, and I would like to redirect all requests from `http://www.example.com/test` to `http://www.example.com:3000`, how do I perform it properly?
I've tried the following:

```
location /test {
    proxy_pass http://www.example.com:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

But what it does is actually redirect `http://www.example.com/test` to `http://www.example.com:3000/test`, and that's not what I want.
How can I do it properly?

**UPDATE:**
While `Krizna`'s answer worked, it redirects me to my domain as expected.
But what I want now is my browser bar to be `http://www.example.com/test` instead of  `http://www.example.com:3000`. If I understand right, I should set nginx to catch response and send it back by url user requested. How can I perform it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this code

```
location / {
   rewrite ^/test(/.*)$ http://example.com:3000$1 permanent;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

**Updated:**
if you don't want to rewrite the URL , try this code..

```
server {
    --------
    server_name  www.example.com;
    location /test {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: include this line too proxy_redirect off;

Comment: This way it redirects to `http://example.com:3000/test`. But keeps browser bar. Any way to keep browser bar but redirect to `http://example.com:3000`?

Comment: okay .. i have tested, current updated code works fine .. just remove **proxy_set_header Host $host;** line

Answer (score 1):

`proxy_redirect off` should solve your issue. It will pass but does not change the URI.

Documentation: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect

```
location /test {
    proxy_pass http://example.com:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Comment: strange, I have this configuration in my server and works like a charm.

Do you have a different server configuration for listen `port 3000`? Because you are redirecting to the same url but with different ports.